# equivalent of php's returning References in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing as [returning references](http://fr.php.net/references.return) in php using javascript ?

for example suppose i want to use a function to find to which variable a reference should be bound, in php i can use an ampersand before a function , how can i do something like this in javascript ?

**EDIT** : if not possible can i do something similar ?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that in JavaScript. The closest you can get is to deal in property names of objects, treating the names as strings. You can then refer to object properties with `obj[ theName ]` to access them.

Comment: Since `window` is an object, you can also conceivably set globals (e.g., `window[theName]`), as we do with phpjs.org in order to reflect the ability in PHP for specifying function names by string--but usually, it is better to just pass in an object, so it is safely namespaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to use references:

```
$obj->value = 2;
echo $myValue; // prints the new value of $obj->value, i.e. 2.
```

Is impossible in Javascript because you can only have two primitives, not two pointers to the same primitive.

There should be another way to accomplish what you want to do though. Without using references.